# Pandas select rows when column value within range from another row column value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create subset from dataframe(100k-500k rows)
with the following format

```
d = {'time':[1,2,3,5,7,9,9.5,10], 'val':['match','match','match','not','not','match','match','match']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

   time    val
0   1.0  match
1   2.0  match
2   3.0  match
3   5.0    not
4   7.0    not
5   9.0  match
6   9.5  match
7  10.0  match
```

I want to select a subset that include all rows when **time**  are within 
limited range.
For example if range is <=1 the first and last three rows are selected

And my desired output:

```
   time    val
0   1.0  match
1   2.0  match
2   3.0  match
5   9.0  match
6   9.5  match
7  10.0  match
```

Comment: how you get output by `if range is <=1`?

Comment: df.time[1]-df.time[0] is 1 so row 0,1 are valid, 
df.time[2]-df.time[1] is 1 so row 1,2 are valid,

Comment: I dont understand, why `3, 4` rows are not valid?

Comment: for row 3 to be valid , another row must exist with time in range (4,6),for row 4 to be valid , another row must exist with time in range (6,8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one line it would look like this:

```
df.loc[(df['time'].diff()<=1)|(df['time'].diff(-1)>=-1)]
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: i am tring to generate the sample of the data that does not work in the 1 line, and work in the 3 line solution

Comment: Please do. My solution assumed you didn't want to reorder your data.

Comment: i just asked an extention to this question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48769603/pandas-select-rows-when-column-value-within-range-from-another-row-column-value hope you can help :)

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution, but i think it is not the best solution

```
dfasc=df.sort_values(['time'], ascending=1)
dfdesc=df.sort_values(['time'], ascending=0)

print (df[(dfasc['time'].diff()<=1.0) | (dfdesc['time'].diff()>=-1.0)])

   time    val
0   1.0  match
1   2.0  match
2   3.0  match
5   9.0  match
6   9.5  match
7  10.0  match
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it so it is vectorized this will work. You may want to used vectorized operations since your DF is so large. You may also want to put it into a function to save memory since I make a few variables below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[1,2,2.5,3,9,9.5,10,11,12],'val':
['not','match','match','match','match','match','match','not','not']})
'''
df
   time    val
0   1.0    not
1   2.0  match
2   2.5  match
3   3.0  match
4   9.0  match
5   9.5  match
6  10.0  match
7  11.0    not
8  12.0    not
'''
x = df.time.values
tmp = (x[1:] - x[:-1]) < 1
fst = tmp[0]
lst = tmp[-1]
mid = np.any([tmp[1:],tmp[:-1]],axis =0)
ans = np.concatenate([[fst],mid,[lst]])
df  = df[ans]
''' Output
   time    val
1   2.0  match
2   2.5  match
3   3.0  match
4   9.0  match
5   9.5  match
6  10.0  match
'''
```

Comment: i dont think it woks,
print(bln) gives 
[False False False False False  True  True]

Comment: @user3394220 fixed